# How do I make numbers in array not adjacent to each other?

Tags: c

I'm developing a simple candy crush game as part of my assignment in my first year.

So I'm stuck at this part where during initialization 3 same numbers must not be adjacent to each other.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//FUNCTION: Draw the Board
int drawBoard()
{
    //Declare array size
    int board[9][9];

    //initialize variables
    int rows, columns, randomNumber;

    //random number seed generator
    srand(time(NULL));

        for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 9 ; rows++ )
        {
            for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 9 ; columns++ )
            {
                //generate random numbers from 2 - 9
                randomNumber = rand() %7 + 2;

                board[rows][columns] = randomNumber;

                printf( "%d\t", board[rows][columns] );

            }//end inner for-loop

            printf("\n\n");
        }//end outer for-loop

}//end FUNCTION drawBoard

int checkAdjacent()
{

}

int main()
{
    drawBoard();
}
```

I thought maybe calling the function `drawBoard()` in the function `checkAdjacent()`, and then use a code like this:

```
if ( board[rows][columns] == randomNumber && 
     board[rows][columns] == randomNumber && 
     board[rows][columns] == randomNumber )
```

Maybe I gotta do this in the drawBoard function but heck I am just confusing myself more and more while scratching my head here :/

Any hints guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure abt the game, but try this: I am checking for adjacency at the time of inserting. Since its a small board, the complexity will not be impacted a lot. Also, since its random, probability of having same adjacent element is also less..

```
    int flag;

    for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 9 ; rows++ )
    {
        for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 9 ; columns++ )
        {
            //generate random numbers from 2 - 9

            flag = 0;
            do{
               randomNumber = rand() % 7 + 2;
               board[rows][columns] = randomNumber;
               if ((board[rows][columns] == board[rows-1][columns]) || (board[rows][columns] == board[rows][columns-1]))
                 flag = 0;
               else 
                 flag = 1; 
            //printf( "%d\t", board[rows][columns] );
             }while(flag == 0);

        }//end inner for-loop

        printf("\n\n");
    }//end outer for-loop
```

Comment: Yeah this is faster and shorter :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you

```
            if((columns > 1) && board[rows][columns - 1] == board[rows][columns - 2]
                           && board[rows][columns - 1] == randomNumber) {
                do {
                    randomNumber = rand() %7 + 2;
                } while (randomNumber == board[rows][columns - 1]);
            }
```

It isn't beautiful, but it works

Comment: Shouldn't it be `rand() % 8 + 2` in order to create numbers from 2 to 9, as he wrote in his original code (I guess it is wrong there as well)

Comment: Hi sorry for the mis-info. It should be numbers from 2 to 8 :)

Answer (score 0):

Not the most optimized code ... but you'll get an idea!

```
# include <iostream>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <conio.h>

//FUNCTION: Draw the Board
void drawBoard()
{
    //Declare array size
    int board[9][9];

    //initialize variables
    int rows, columns, randomNumber;
    int x, y, z;

    //random number seed generator
    srand(time(NULL));

        for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 9 ; rows++ )
        {
            for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 9 ; columns++ )
            {
                //generate random numbers from 2 - 9
                randomNumber = rand() %7 + 2;
                board[rows][columns] = randomNumber;
                printf( "%d\t", board[rows][columns] );
            } //end inner for-loop
            printf("\n\n");
        } //end outer for-loop

        // Checking triple values - Horizontal values
        for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 9 ; rows++ )
        {
            printf ("\n");
            for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 7 ; columns++ )
            {
                printf ("%d %d %d - ", board[rows][columns], board[rows][columns+1], board[rows][columns+2]);
                x = board[rows][columns];
                y = board[rows][columns+1];
                z = board[rows][columns+2];

                if ((x == y) && (y == z))
                    printf ("Found\n");
                else
                    printf ("Nop\n");
                if (columns == 7)
                    break;
            } //end inner for-loop
        } //end outer for-loop

}//end FUNCTION drawBoard

int main()
{
    drawBoard();
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Oooh yeah. I get it now! Thanks! =) Thanks for your answers too kirti and Dmitriy!

Comment: btw, should the triple-check conditions for columns be <= 7? if columns can only be added to a maximum of 2 times, wouldn't the checking go up to the 8th column only?

Comment: I did it with < 8 (which is same as <=7). If you look at my program output you will see the program try to match 2 numbers from last column with the next number from next row - first column! To prevent that I had to use < 7 [the loop will continue 7 times] instead of < =7 [re-run the code few times and compare the output]